# How to stop code execution after routing to error page from vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I have a cart page written with VueJs and Vuex. I have an api file that acts as a wrapper around axios.

In my vuex action, I call the API and if it was successful I commit data into my mutation.

```
async await mounted () {
   const result = this.getStatus()
   if (result === "locked") {
      this.$router.push({name: "LockedPage"}
   }
   else if (result === "expired") {
      this.$router.push({name: "SessionExpiredPage"}
   }

   doSomething(result)
},
methods: {
  function doSomething(res) {
    // does something with result
  }
}
```

The getStatus function here is from my vuex action.

```
     const {authid, authpwd} = router.history.current.params
     if (!authid || !authpwd) {
       router.push({name: "SomethingWrong"})
       return
     }
     const res = await api.getStatus 
     commit("SET_STATUS", res.status)
     if (res.otherLogic) {
       //commit or trigger other actions
     }

     return status
   }
```

What's the ideal way to handle these kind of API errors? If you look you'll see that I'm routing inside the Outer component's mounted hook as well as inside the vuex action itself. Should all the routing for this status function just happen inside the vuex action?

I think how it is currently set up, when the`SomethingWrong page` get's routed. It'll return execution back to the `mounted` function still. So technically the `doSomething` function can still be called but I guess with undefined values. This seems kind of bad. Is there a way to stop code execution after we route the user to the error page? Would it be better to throw an error after routing the page?

Should I use `Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info)` to catch these custom route erorrs I throw from the vuex action?

Answer (score 0):

For general errors like expired session I would recommend handle it low at axios level, using interceptor. https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Interceptors can be defined eg. in plugins. Adding Nuxt plugin as example (Vue without Nuxt will use little bit different plugin definition, but still it should be useful as inspiration) (Also window is access because snippet is from SPA application - no server side rendering)

```
export default ({ $axios, redirect }) => {
  $axios.onError((error) => {
    const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
    if (code === 401) {
      // don't use route path, because error is happending before transition is completed
      if (!window.localStorage.getItem('auth.redirect')) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('auth.redirect', window.location.pathname)
      }
      redirect('/login-page')
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: when you handle routing with the interceptor are you catching the error where you invoked axios?

Are you doing something like `axios.loginUser().catch(error =>{ // this is called after redirect to login-page})